# Unable to login to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, forge, laravel-forge

My AWS EC2 instance (20.04 LTS) created using laravel suddenly got down and I am unable to login with ssh. I stop the instance and started again several times, but still it is showing the error attached. So I cannot use the server. For time being I have recreated a new instance, but I like to know what could be the possible issue. Please let me know how can reuse the instance

Also, as my AWS plan does not support for "Technical Support", I don't know how to contact to AWS. Pleas let me know if anyone knows how can I contact for such issue.

Attached screenshot for your reference:
[image: several]

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the server? with a pem file? Did you try to connect to the instance from browser?

Comment: From browser only by login into AWS account

Comment: There might be several reasons, can you give me access to the instance as an IAM user?